# No Longer Exists

Tags: grammar

Are both versions gramatically correct?:

"The opposition between good and evil no longer exists."

"The opposition between good and evil does no longer exist."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, these are both correct, and have the same meaning. However, your second example doesn’t sound very natural; normally, we use *do* in English to show emphasis, in the affirmative:

> — Does the opposition between good and evil exist any longer?
>
> — It *does* still exist!

If you want to add emphasis to “no longer”, you can phrase it negatively, with “any longer”.

> The opposition between good and evil *doesn’t* exist *any longer*.

Answer (score 6):

> The opposition between good and evil no longer exists. [normal]

The above is the normal way of saying it.

> The opposition between good and evil does no longer exist. [unidiomatic]

Strictly speaking the above is grammatically possible but no-one would ever say it.

> The opposition between good and evil  exists no longer. [dramatic]

That sounds overdramatic as though you are making a speech.

If you want to use 'to do' then you should say:

> The opposition between good and evil does not exist any longer. [emphatic]